Motivations for the Flowout Theorem
This is my first encounter with the Flowout theorem,

(image taken from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds book) and I can't see the motivation from which it comes. Lee says it's the ground for many geometrical constructions on manifolds, but doesn't go further on that comment.
What are the specific motivations for this theorem?
On the other hand, item (c) has a slightly similar flavour to tubular neighbourhoods. Has $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_{\delta})$ something to do with that later concept? Something like "One should think about it as a weak version of tubular neighbourhood"...
Thank you in advance for any guide.
